# When Checkbox is Checked send to another page C# Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, checkbox, xamarin

I am writing an app that allows the user to select a phrase in the form of a checkbox. When the user selects get results the checkbox needs to go to another page. At first I had the text from the checkbox selected go to an edit text which is what is written in the code below but I need it to go to the other page as a checkbox. How would I do this? This is the code I have for sending the checkbox to edit text. What changes would I need to achieve the above?

```
    public class numbersActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    { 
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        //Variables
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.numbers);
        CheckBox cb0 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox0);
        CheckBox cb1 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox cb2 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox cb3 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox3);
        Button button0 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button0);
        //Back Button
        button0.Click += delegate {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };
        //Get Results button
        Button button01 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button01);
            button01.Click += delegate {
            if (cb0.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb0 + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    };
            if (cb1.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb1.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;

                    };
            if (cb2.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb2.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    };
            if (cb3.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb3.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    };
            StartActivity (typeof(results));
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you are trying to pass a value to another activity you should have a look here http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly what I needed. i did not know the correct terms for what I needed.